# What should one do to ensure ABS sticks to bed?

Tags: extrusion, abs

I'm trying to print with ABS plastic. I've only used PLA before. I'm using Anycubic Kobra Neo (Heated, PEI-coated bed). Originally, I just changed my plastic to ABS and tried printing with manufacturer-provided profile (80/230 degrees), without changing Z-offset or any other details. However, plastic just didn't stick to the bed. Since then, I've tried:

- Increasing temperatures to 90/240
- Increasing and decreasing extrusion force
- Increasing and decresing Z-offset
- Performing autolevelling
- Checking that it extrudes properly without print (using filament loading procedure)

Nothing seems to help. Every time, it starts printing the "border" (not sure how it is called) more or less fine:

[image: Border image]

But then it either leaves peaces of plastic on the bed, or they just stick to the extruder:

[image: Extruder picture]

Are there any other steps I should check to ensure proper adhesion? I'm aware that it is recommended to use things like glue to increase adhesion when printing ABS, but I thought it is possible to print without them if the bed is heated and has PEI (or other) special coating.

Comment: You need an enclosure and an adhesive like 3DLAC, Dimafix or Magigoo or any other adhesive (ABS sludge). Also, ABS is outperformed on many properties (not all), so why should you use ABS? E.g. PETG and ASA are better printable alternatives.

Comment: @0scar, I'm new to 3D printing, and I wanted to by some filament, so I just went with ABS. I knew that it required higher temperatures to print, but it was listed as supported by my printer, so I decided to try it out. Is PETG better when it comes to printing, though? From what I've read, it still requires adhesives and high temperatures (higher then PLA, at least)

Comment: use the ABS for your weed-whacker and buy some cheap PLA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use glue sticks around the footprint of what you will be printing.  Never had a problem after that. Another alternative is to use some masking tape.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!